# Использование `flexbox` и поддерживание соотношение сторон 1:1, даже если размер контента разный

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть много вопросов на `SO` о поддержании соотношения сторон элемента (с помощью `flexbox` или без него).

Однако моя проблема несколько отличается, поскольку я хочу переопределить соотношение сторон  дочернего изображения.

1. Убедитесь, что изображение полностью покрывает элемент (`object-fit: cover`)
2. Убедитесь, что элемент равен 1: 1 (т.е. Идеальный круг)
3. Убедитесь, что `overflowing image is hidden`

Другими словами, изображение должно вести себя так, как если бы это был фон элемента (я не могу использовать их в качестве фоновых изображений), из которых соотношение сторон всегда 1: 1 и адаптивно.

В приведенном ниже примере все работает отлично, за исключением того, что элементы `<a>` адаптируются к их потомкам изображения. Но я хочу, чтобы они поддерживали соотношение 1: 1, чтобы получить идеальные круги. 
(Средний из первого ряда должен быть больше, чем остальные).

`HTML` не может измениться, но я могу использовать современные свойства `CSS`, такие как `object-fit` и `flexbox`. (Пока это поддерживают  последние версии Chrome / Firefox)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.img-gallery {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 24px;
  min-width: 320px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-gallery .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.img-gallery a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #004494 0%, #7db9e8 78%, #c2dfed 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 3px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 24px;
  transition: padding 200ms;
}

.img-gallery a:hover,
#s_country .img-gallery .row:first-of-type a:nth-child(2):hover {
  padding: 0;
}

.img-gallery a:hover span {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

.img-gallery .row:first-of-type a:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  width: 30%;
  width: calc((60% - 96px) / 2);
}

.img-gallery .row:first-of-type a:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 2;
  padding: 4px;
}

.img-gallery span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 250ms;
  z-index: 2;
}

.img-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-gallery span::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 48%, #ffc5e7 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .72;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b3/9c/54/b39c54776074d07ee0b567826768730a.jpg" id="img-1-3"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d6/df/51/d6df512a2f15f517767b4d82d2d97a4c.jpg" id="img-1-4"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ec/a9/dd/eca9dd106a04cdbee399870252ef711f.jpg" id="img-1-5"></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7d/01/19/7d0119a2fec989e208f288326c7cad0f.jpg" id="img-1-6"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d8/c3/32/d8c332d09b03673845b2e92a48816233.jpg" id="img-1-7"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/88/3b/dd/883bddab14168f5f0807fec021002d8d.jpg" id="img-1-8"></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8e/4f/bb/8e4fbb89b155d15521b80d1baf9290d1.jpg" id="img-1-9"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Код, иллюстрирующий, когда код Терри не работает: `landscape pictures`.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.img-gallery {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 24px;
  min-width: 320px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-gallery .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.img-gallery a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #004494 0%, #7db9e8 78%, #c2dfed 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 3px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 24px;
  transition: padding 200ms;
}

.img-gallery .row:first-of-type a:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  width: 30%;
  width: calc((60% - 96px) / 2);
}

.img-gallery .row:first-of-type a:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 2;
  padding: 4px;
}

.img-gallery span {
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 250ms;
  z-index: 2;
}

.img-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}

.img-gallery a:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

.img-gallery span::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 48%, #ffc5e7 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .72;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b3/9c/54/b39c54776074d07ee0b567826768730a.jpg" id="img-1-3"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d6/df/51/d6df512a2f15f517767b4d82d2d97a4c.jpg" id="img-1-4"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ec/a9/dd/eca9dd106a04cdbee399870252ef711f.jpg" id="img-1-5"></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7d/01/19/7d0119a2fec989e208f288326c7cad0f.jpg" id="img-1-6"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d8/c3/32/d8c332d09b03673845b2e92a48816233.jpg" id="img-1-7"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/13/7c/3d/137c3d3bd9f25aa9d2677136d9336d74.jpg" id="img-1-8"></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8e/4f/bb/8e4fbb89b155d15521b80d1baf9290d1.jpg" id="img-1-9"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/44009015/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы сохранить соотношение сторон адаптивных элементов, вы можете использовать [`padding technique`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Обратите внимание, что вы не должны использовать проценты при заполнении `bottom/top` части для `flex children`, [см. Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717953/padding-bottom-top-in-flexbox-layout) для получения дополнительной информации.

Вы можете создать сетку [адаптивных квадратов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares) и добавить `border-radius`, чтобы сделать их кругами.

Для изображений `object-fit: cover;` свойство делает именно то, что вам нужно: сохранить исходное соотношение сторон изображения и полностью покрыть элемент.

Я изменил первое изображение на ландшафтное изображение, чтобы показать, что эта техника работает и с этими.

Вот пример того, как вы можете достичь своей цели (я убрал некоторые из ваших `CSS` свойств, чтобы демонстрация была простой):

```css
*,*::before,*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.img-gallery {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 24px;
  min-width: 320px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-gallery .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.img-gallery a {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #004494 0%, #7db9e8 78%, #c2dfed 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 24px;
}
.img-gallery a::before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  padding-bottom:100%;
}


.img-gallery .row:first-of-type a:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  width: 30%;
  width: calc((60% - 96px) / 2);
}

.img-gallery .row:first-of-type a:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 2;
}

.img-gallery span {
  position:absolute;
  top:3px;left:3px;right:3px;bottom:3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}

.img-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition:transform 0.5s;
}
.img-gallery a:hover img{
  transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg" id="img-1-3"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d6/df/51/d6df512a2f15f517767b4d82d2d97a4c.jpg" id="img-1-4"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ec/a9/dd/eca9dd106a04cdbee399870252ef711f.jpg" id="img-1-5"></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7d/01/19/7d0119a2fec989e208f288326c7cad0f.jpg" id="img-1-6"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d8/c3/32/d8c332d09b03673845b2e92a48816233.jpg" id="img-1-7"></span></a>
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/88/3b/dd/883bddab14168f5f0807fec021002d8d.jpg" id="img-1-8"></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" title="Show large image"><span><img itemprop="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8e/4f/bb/8e4fbb89b155d15521b80d1baf9290d1.jpg" id="img-1-9"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44009015/7394871)